# Where is configured a UDP connection in JBoss 7?

Tags: linux, security, port, jboss7.x, java-7

I launch JBoss 7 on Centos6 using JDK7.
When I check what port is opened I see the following UDP port:

```
netstat -ntulp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
udp        0      0 :::43676                    :::*                                    2460/java
```

The port is changing its value each time I restart JBoss.
Where and why the UDP connection is configured?

I use  `standalone\configuration\standalone.xml` and I can not find any UDP configuration there.

**Added**

I have commended out `management-native` socket-binding and use only `management-http` socket-binding.

I still can see opened UDP port and I want to close it.

Please help.

Comment: I am totally newbie on JBoss. However, thought that this link may help you http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Clustering_Guide/beta422/html/jbosscache-jgroups-transport-udp.html

Comment: Please note that I did not configured clustering (I use standalone) but UDP port still opened. I want to close it.

Answer (score 1):

JBoss used an ephemeral port for clustering. An old version of the documentation for "JGroups" is [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html/jgroups.chapt.html#jgroups-configuration).

Another possibility is that it is the JMX port used for the JBoss management interface.

Comment: Thanks (+1). I found the similar configuration `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:1.1" default-stack="udp"...>` in `standalone\configuration\standalone-full-ha.xml` and in `standalone\configuration\standalone-ha.xml`. Can not find it in the configuration I use `standalone\configuration\standalone.xml`. Where it can be configured in JBoss7?